# Returning the Line BEFORE a Table in Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, text-extraction

I am trying to write an Excel VBA Script to extract data from 12 years worth of Trivia Sheets I have written in Word.

The result will be a big Excel file of Trivia Questions and Answers

I haven't Coded anything for SO LONG, but I'm getting there...

I want to Copy the text that Exists BEFORE a Table...

The titles are circled in yellow:

[image]

I can find the table well enough, but cannot come up with code to extract the Titles that are BEFORE... but not actually a PART of the Table...

Stu

Can anyone help?

Comment: If it's Word - Get the first paragraph of the table and refer to the previous paragraph? Something like `ThisDocument.Tables(1).Range.Paragraphs(1).Previous.Range.Text` might work. Why did you tag `excel` anyway?

Comment: Is it Excel or Word document you are referring to?

Comment: Its VBA code in Excel to extract the text from any one of thousands of WORD files and place it into, what will end up being a VERY BIG .Xls

Comment: @StuFisher In that case, the use of `ThisDocument` is not correct as it's not in Word VBA, so assuming that you have set the document to a variable `wordDoc` then it would be `wordDoc.Tables(1).Range.Paragraphs(1).Previous.Range.Text`. You need to include your code of how you are getting the table if you want more specific help.

Comment: @RaymondWu

that seems to have done it.. you are a gentleman and scholar! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that there is no empty paragraph(s) between the table and the text, you can access that paragraph text by using the [Previous](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.paragraph.previous) method of the table's first paragraph like so:

```
'Assuming you have set the word document to the variable wordDoc
wordDoc.Tables(1).Range.Paragraphs(1).Previous.Range.Text
```